# Value posts firstly and then only it finishes input (if clicked). needed backwards(code is corect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have dropdown list of country suggestions and input above. When i click on one of them - AJAX should work(and it does) and add value to #msg_native. HTML:

```
echo '<div class="search_native"><input type="text" name="native_input" id="native"/>';
echo "<div id='output'></div></div>";
```

All JQUERY :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        $array = ['usa','france','germany'];
        $input_val = $("input[name='native_input']").val();
        $('#output').text('')
        r = new RegExp($input_val)
        for (i = 0; i < $array.length; i++) {
            if ($array[i].match(r)) {
                $('#output').append('<p class="match">' + $array[i] + '</p>')
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.match', function(){

        $value = $(this).text(); 
        $('#native').val($value);
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#native').change(function() {
        alert('cl');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "home.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true,
            data: {native_input: $("input[name='native_input']").val()},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);  
                $("#msg_native").after(data);   
            }});
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that the value that gets posted is only what Ive typed myself, regardless on clicked element. But I want complete value- not only typed letters...so it firstly posts value and then 'finishes' the input (if clicked)
What can you practically advice to me?

```
data: {native_input: $value},
```

returns empty string

Comment: you mean the value you got from here is the value you typed rather then the one you selected?
 $(document).on('click', '.match', function(){

        $value = $(this).text(); 
        $('#native').val($value);
    });

Comment: The problem is that the `change` event is being triggered as soon as you leave the input field to click on `.match`, so it sends the AJAX request before that has updated the input field. You should send the AJAX when the user has clicked a Submit button or pressed Return **after** you've updated the field.

Comment: yes, well..thats the idea - i make the container that have info inputs alike - no save...how can i make it?

Comment: A post that states "code is corect" probably isn't.  On thing I used to teach when I did instruction was to change your mindset in development to "How can I repair this or make this better?" followed closely by "How can I make this simpler or remove stuff not needed?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of this might be debatable but I put those in place for maintainability of the code and/or to match the most recent jQuery.

- Only use one document ready handler (if possible)
- Remove all the global objects (put `var` in front of them)
- Use the `native` id when possible as fastest selector (not `$("input[name='native_input']")` for instance)
- use `this` in the event handler, not the full selector (see next item)
- If I enter "France" not "france" match does not work so need to case that input to equality `var $input_val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();`
- You start with an empty field, might be good to show the match for that - simply trigger the keyup on startup to show all the array: `}).trigger('keyup');`  Now they are available for your clicking.
- Attach the click handler on the wrapper for the "match" elements: `$('#output').on('click', '.match', function() {`
- Use the promise form of the ajax `.done(`
- Create a new custom event instead of the "change" on the `native`. We can then trigger that event as/when needed (the real issue you describe) Example: `$('#native').trigger('myMatch');` and as I use it here:

trigger the event on a full match:

```
if (jQuery.inArray($input_val, $array) !== -1) {
  $(this).trigger('myMatch');
}
```

**Revised code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#native").on('keyup', function() {
    var $array = ['usa', 'france', 'germany'];
    var $input_val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#output').html('');
    var r = new RegExp($input_val);
    for (var i = 0; i < $array.length; i++) {
      if ($array[i].match(r)) {
        $('#output').append('<p class="match">' + $array[i] + '</p>');
      }
    }
    // full match entered, trigger the match
    if (jQuery.inArray($input_val, $array) !== -1) {
      $(this).trigger('myMatch');
    }
  }).on('myMatch', function() {
    alert('cl');
    var nativeMatch = {
      native_input: $("#native").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "home.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      encode: true,
      data: nativeMatch,
      cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
      alert(data);
      $("#msg_native").after(data);
    });
    return false;
  }).trigger('keyup');
  $('#output').on('click', '.match', function() {
    var $value = $(this).text();
    $('#native').val($value).trigger('myMatch');
  });
});
```